# Updating sub arrays concurrently with std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I'm trying to update an array in a game loop concurrently by splitting it into smaller arrays

```
//sample code but 'arr' can be of any type
const int size = 1000000;
double arr[size];
while(running)
{
    double dt = delta();
    auto a = std::async([&](double tdt)
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
             arr[i] *= tdt;
     }, dt);
    auto b = std::async([&](double tdt)
     {
         for(int i = size / 2; i < size; i++)
             arr[i] *= tdt;
     }, dt);

     /*do something with arr after*/

}
```

but I'm not really sure what I'm doing here.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: how do I update sub arrays concurrently by using std::async in a game loop

Comment: the array is n't initialized already and why didn't you use std::vector or std::array

Comment: your array is very huge, so use std::vector. and it isn't initialized too.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify it, no need to put relevant info into comments. Still, you seem to have picked the tools for your task already, so why not go the next step and simply try to use them? That way you wouldn't have to ask questions that can be answered by doing basic research. However, after doing that, ask yourself what you want to achieve with all this, because that determines whether your initial pick of tools was actually a good one. ;)